# using script function rather than keyboard input

Tags: shell, shell-script, x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I'm writing a shell script to change a user's password. I tried to use the `passwd` command, but that command always asks for the old and new passwords to be typed; it won't accept them from my script.

Is there a way to change the user's password in a shell script, with the old and new password coming from e.g., variables?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714915/using-the-passwd-command-from-within-a-shell-script

Comment: I've edited your question substantially in an attempt to write it in "proper" English. If I've lost your intent, please feel free to [edit] or revert my edit.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn passwd username
expect "New password:"
send -- "user-password\r"
expect "Retype new password:"
send -- "user-password\r"
expect eof
```

**Testing**

I saved it as `script.exp` and when I run the script, this is the output I get in my machine.

```
expect script.exp
spawn passwd ramesh
Changing password for user ramesh.
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
```

I did not had to type in the password using my keyboard. Of course, you could modify the function to further suit your requirements and use it the way you want.